# Setting web page background image on all parts of the page that do not contain controls

Tags: css, asp.net, html

I am adding background images to the existing pages on a web site.  I have been asked to do this is in such a way that the image shows up everywhere on the page EXCEPT for the rectangle that encompasses all of the existing controls, etc on the page.  In this rectangle, the background color will remain white as it is today.  Here is a link to a page that shows how the pages are supposed to look once the modifications are done:
     http://www.maestroweb.com/default_bgtest3.aspx

I have experimented with multiple ways to do this.  For example, I tried adding

```
<div style="background-color: white">
```

or

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" BackColor="White">
```

around the existing controls.  These methods correctly "determine" the height of the rectangle but the width is set to the width of the window and that is not what I want.  I could add width attributes but the controls on the pages have different widths and sometimes change.

The best solution I have come up with so far is something like this:

```
<table bgcolor="White" align="center"><tr><td>
    <%-- All of the page's controls, etc. --%>
</td></tr></table>
```

This works.  The rectangle is correctly sized and its background remains white.  The new background image only shows up where it is supposed to.

My problem is that the solution above seems kludgey to me.  Is there a better way to accomplish the same goal?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the css property **background-size: cover**

```css
body {
  background: url('http://www.maestroweb.com/6/winter.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}
.content-wrapper {
  height: 400px;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input Frederic.  Your content wrapper class comes close to what I need but doesn't quite do everything.  I have to modify a couple hundred pages.  The content in each of them has a different height and width.  I used <table> because it automatically handles different heights and widths.  Is there a way to adjust your class to do the same thing?

Comment: I don't understand your usage of table. Can you write a fiddle? And use a html template to wrap your pages, it's hard to maintain otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me Frederic.  I might be able to use an html template but I have to see how best to integrate that into the rest of my app.  But, I'm not sure what you mean by "a fiddle".  Can you explain that term?

Comment: One other thing, I used a table because it does automatically much of what I wanted a div to do; namely handle the height and width of the region surrounding the content.  But, I do understand the maintenance difficulty problems.  That's why I posted the question.

Comment: jsfiddle is a tool to share your code snippets http://jsfiddle.net/
You don't need to use a table in your case, I think you should use a div and center it. Do you still have questions?